# Issue creating users on mysql/mariadb on amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

Still trying to figure out RDS on AWS. I setup an EC2 instance that I can SSH into.  I then created an RDS instance of MariaDB.  I can SSH into my EC2 and then use MySQL to connect to the RDS instance using the username/password I created when I setup the RDS instance.  When I look at the users I see

```
'myusername'@'%' 
'rdsadmin'@'localhost'
```

While logged in as 'myusername' to the mysql db, I create a new user with more limited hosts:

```
CREATE USER 'otheruser'@'nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn' IDENTIFIED BY 'good_password'
```

No problems so far.  Now give 'otheruser' some permissions:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'otheruser'@'nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn' IDENTIFIED BY 'same_password';
```

Seems to work.  From my IP address I can use Navicat to connect as 'otheruser' to 'mydatabase' and can create tables, add data, drop tables, create indexes no problem.  However, when I do this, all privileges show 'N':

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'otheruser'\G
```

If I look in information_schema the only privilege is 'usage'

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges;
```

If, as my root user created during RDS setup I try to specify a specific privilege for 'otheruser' I get an access denied error.

So if all of the permissions are showing 'N', and information_scheme just shows 'usage', how is Navicat able to connect as that user and do pretty much everything?

What's the correct way of creating a restricted user on an RDS instance?  It seems the user created during instance creation is slightly limited vs. the 'rdsadmin'@'localhost', but AFAIK there's now way to connect to the RDS from localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The privileges in the mysql.user table are global privileges.  They apply to all databases on the server, present and future.  You didn't issue a statement that would grant any of those.

`SELECT * FROM mysql.db;` will show you where the navicat user's permissions you granted can be found.

You can `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_database.*` in RDS, which grants only the database-level permissions for that one database.

...but you cannot `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*` because you, the master user, do not possess all global privileges.  RDS doesn't give them to you.  To do global grants, you have to grant specific privileges.

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myusername@'%';`

The privileges you see listed there are the only global (server-level) privileges you can grant.

Yes, the things you can do with the privileges provided by RDS are limited, presumably because it's a managed service... so they don't want you to be able to break anything that they would have to fix for you... which they would, because it's a managed service.  That's one of the drawbacks of RDS.  You trade some flexibility for ease of administration (point in time recovery, creation/monitoring/destruction of read replicas, backup snapshots, etc.).

`rdsadmin@localhost` is the account the RDS infrastructure uses to manage and monitor your instance. That's why it has all those privs.  You're correct -- you can't log in from localhost.  Only the RDS supervisory process can.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!